# how to get emails from my website without using mailto tag

Tags: html, css

I have this code right here I want persons to be able to send me a message from this code without using mail to tag how do I do that?

```
enter code here
<form class="form-inline" role="form" style="text-align: center;"
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" style="font-family:'Handlee', cursive;">
<input type="Email" placeholder="Email" style="font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;"><br>
<textarea placeholder="               type Here  "></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" 
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

Comment: Pls provide more information. What web/application server that you are using? What you had try so far? You need to write code at server site. It cannot be done using pure html.

Answer (score 0):

A search on Stackoverflow...
  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+form

Some Google searches for Email Forms just to find a few...

[PHP email form](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=php+email+form)

[cgi email form](https://www.google.com/search?q=cgi+email+form)

[python email form](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=python+email+form)

[asp.net email form](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=asp.net+email+form)

[cgi email form](https://www.google.com/search?q=cgi+email+form)